# How can I keep away from latinate?

Tags: etymology, latin, resources, germanic-languages

Are there resources to help me keep away from latinate when I write? Preferably, they would let me trade latinate words for older, better words.

A thesaurus might help (or better, a good dictionary with information on etymology, combined with a thesaurus---which is the combination I used to find that “keep away” could replace “avoid”), but there are problems with the dictionary+thesaurus approach. The dictionary will give me the origin of a word, but no non-Latinate alternatives, while a thesaurus will give me many alternatives, but won't give the etymological information I need to tell whether a word is latinate or not. A writer like me who seeks to occasionally (but quickly) replace Latinate words with non-Latinate words is then forced into an iterative search that can be time-consuming.

But what makes me think that writers should replace Latinate with "older, better words," and what makes them better, asks a user. The idea that avoiding Latinate can improve writing is fairly widespread, and I offer three sources to support this claim. More sources can easily be found.  The first source is, of course, Ernest Hemingway. Note his (partial) avoidance of Latinate in the following quote:

> Poor Faulkner. Does he really think big emotions come from big words?
> He thinks I don’t know the ten-dollar words. I know them all right.
> But there are older and simpler and better words, and those are the
> ones I use.

But I suspect that the user finds Hemingway distasteful, which is fair enough. As an alternative then, take the minor classic *Economical Writing* by Deirdre (formerly Donald) McCloskey. McCloskey advises against the use of "five-dollar words to support a pose of The Scientist or The Scholar." She explains,

> "Anglo-Saxon words [...] have often acquired a homely concreteness
> through long use that more recent and more scholarly coinages from
> Latin or Greek have not [...].

But then, McCloskey is an economist, and the user most assuredly will not take advice on usage from economists (not with a B.A. in English and 20 years of book-tending under her belt). Perhaps a passage from a higher authority and with more historical flair will bring the said user around. The passage comes from  *Style: Toward Clarity and Grace* by Joseph Williams. Deep breath, I quote at length (the final paragraph delivers the punch):

> After the Norman Conquest, those responsible for institu­tional,
> scholarly, and religious affairs wrote in Latin and later Norman
> French. In the late fourteenth and early fifteenth cen­turies,
> increasing numbers of writers began using English again for matters of
> state, commercial, and social life. But since the na­tive vocabulary
> for these matters had long since disappeared (or had never come into
> being), English writers were able to write about them in the only
> vocabulary available, in words borrowed from Latin, but particularly
> from French. [...]
>
> Conspiring with that influence on our vocabulary was a sec­ond one,
> the Renaissance. In the sixteenth century, as England was increasingly
> influenced by classical writers, scholars began translating into
> English large numbers of Greek and Latin texts. [...]
>
> As a consequence of these two influences, our vocabulary is the most
> varied of any modern European language. [...] But this flexibility has come with a
> price. Since the language of political, cultural, scientific, and
> economic affairs is based largely on Romance words, those of us who
> aspire to participate have had to learn a vocabulary separate from
> that which we learned through the first five or ten years of our
> lives. Just as we have to spend a good deal of time in school learning
> the idiosyncrasies of our spelling system and of "good" grammar, so
> must we spend time learning words not rooted in our daily experience. [...]
>
> And of course once we learn these words, who among us can resist using
> them when we want to sound learned and authoritative? Writers began to
> surrender to that temptation well before the middle of the sixteenth
> century, but it was about then that many English writers became so
> enamored with an erudite vocabulary that they began deliberately to
> lard their prose with exotic Latinisms, a kind of writing that came to
> be known as the "inkhorn" style and was mocked as pretentious and
> incomprehensible by those critics for whom English had become a
> special passion. This impulse toward an elevated diction has proved
> quite durable; it accounts for the difference today between "The
> adolescents who had effectuated forcible entry into the domicile were
> apprehended" and "We caught the kids who broke into the house.”

I hope these quotes help to explain my interest in avoiding Latinate

To be clear though, I don't seek to avoid all Latinate. I am no extremist. But in some cases, in my scientific writing (I am an economist, as you may have guessed), I find that non-Latinate words can bring more clarity to the reader.

I'm looking for useful tips especially for *dedicated* resources (not general dictionaries and thesauruses) that will allow me to quickly exchange Latinate for non-Latinate. I hope the post-police will let this question through now, so that Canned Man, John Lawler, myself and others can have a productive discussion on this interesting topic.

I know about [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Germanic_and_Latinate_equivalents_in_English), but it's too short. A bodily book I can buy and hold would be best.

---

Is this "writing advice (off-topic)"?

No, this is "word choice and usage" and therefore "welcomed here", at least according to the [help page](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Am I requesting a list?

What I am actually after are dedicated resources (rather than general dictionaries and thesauruses), as well as tips and methods that will help writers of the English language improve their usage by avoiding Latinate. ("Usage", after all, does appear in the title of this stack, i.e. "English Language & Usage".)

Comment: This is either writing advice (off-topic) or a request for lists (off-topic) or can be answered by common references like a thesaurus (so off-topic). Sorry. The answer probably is "Buy a thesaurus, if you want a real book".

Comment: Where have you got the idea that Latin-derived words are in some way inferior?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is requesting writing advice or it is requesting a list (both of which are off-topic for EL&U.)

Comment: I see this as a valid request for resources (lists of English words of non-classical origins); why has it been closed rather than migrated to ELU Meta? Are such resources off-topic there too?

Comment: Yes, I could have gone on to say that I was aware that in some cases a traditional 'Anglo-Saxon' word is preferred by many people to a pretentious Latin-derived one - but as your original question was very brief, I made only a brief comment.

Comment: Kate, you had no idea about any of this, let’s be honest with each other.

Comment: I have yet to see a subway with dominated by words with Latin roots. Why say *Expectoration prohibited* when a simple *No spitting* says it all?

Comment: Exactly rajan9, exactly.

Comment: Let’s get this question reopened, brother!

Comment: I have flagged this question for moderator intervention, requesting it to be reopened.

Comment: I would further advise that you edit your quote; not all of it is necessary to get the point across in this – our – context.

Comment: You ask and I deliver!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst I agree with the commenters, I will try to help you on your way. I think what you are looking for is Pure English, that is: Anglish. A good place to start is [The Anglish Moot](https://anglish.fandom.com/), which is hosted by a Wiki page which collects knowledge and includes a thesaurus and a dictionary for use in daily speech and writing. They also have a link to a Discord. Another source is Anglish Wiki, which also host [an Anglish dictionary](https://anglish.miraheze.org/wiki/Everyday_Anglish_Words).

For physical books, consider finding a book of  William Barnes’s poetry. Yes, that is [straight from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_purism_in_English#Modern_English), and so is this:

> The September 2009 publication *How We’d Talk if the English had Won in 1066* by David Cowley updates Old English words to today’s English spelling, seeking mainstream appeal by covering words in five grades ranging from “easy” to “weird and wonderful” and giving many examples of use with drawings and tests.[24] Paul Kingsnorth’s 2014 *The Wake* is written in a hybrid of Old English and Modern English to account for its 1066 milieu,[25] and Edmund Fairfax’s 2017 satiric literary novel *Outlaws* is similarly written in a “constructed” form of English consisting almost exclusively of words of Germanic origin.[26]

I must state, though, that I am not even sure I should be posting this answer, as it is so far from what EL&U is about. If the question was rephrased, stating some examples of what you are looking for, and was not just simply a ‘Where can I find this thing?’, your question would have been received better. I am sorry, this is a bit harsh, but I do feel that this question in its current state comes across as not showing effort.

Comment: Barnes wrote a grammar, too. [_An Outline of English Speech-craft](https://books.google.com/books?id=K60VAAAAYAAJ&hl=en), published in 1878 by Kegan Paul and now available online. You can print it out. This is a metagrammar, written in English re-imagined without Romance roots (though Norse roots are OK, it appears).

Comment: These resources are very helpful. I'm actually looking for modern resources, I've edited my question, I hope it will be better received (but I doubt that it will be, in these uncharitable halls).

Comment: Also, I didn’t mean to suggest that these resources are not modern or not what I’m after, they’re perfect, thanks again.

Comment: @JohnLawler Considering Emonds and Faarlund’s research (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/271494996_English_The_Language_of_the_Vikings), that does make sense. Though this critique of their research (https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/nordic-journal-of-linguistics/article/english-is-still-a-west-germanic-language/FFF1593D4EC6A2E7D9671595509F0815) is well worth reading.

Comment: @RMM. It is much improved. I would suggest you re-edit it to remove the snarkiness, and we will be well on our way to having a good discussion. As you can see above, I have suggested it is reopened.